# sparkjava: Load PNG as base64 from InputStream

Tags: java, base64, png, inputstream, spark-java

I have the following method to load resources as String where `path` is the String to the resource on my classpath (which works just fine on plain text):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path))) {
        return scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
}
```

Now I want to load a PNG image as a base64 String so I  can send it back through sparkjava with `Content-Type: image/png`.

How can I do that?

**Do not use any libraries, only plain old Java.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the MIME type in the header with `response.header("Content-Type", "image/png")` (look up your MIME type [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)), you can use this:

```
try {
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(MyClass.class.getResource(path).toURI()));
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
```

---

Apart from that, to base64-encode a `String` in Java 8,  you can use the [`java.util.Base64.Encoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) class, so you'd just run the result of the method I posted in my description through

```
Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(resourceAsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

and send it back as response. I haven't got it to work for me though, for some odd reason. I simply used my framework's static files feature.